# Need advice on customizing RSS feed

Tags: javascript, php, rss, simplexml

Hi I need an advice on how to reorganize our rss feeds via php or js, currently it shows everything with the newest ad on top.

We need the following rules to be implemented.

1.) Show item if item pubdate is today if older remove/disregard

2.) If item pubdate is older than 7 Days show it at the top of the list.

Then output it the same way as a rss

Many thanks

RSS Sample

```
<item>
<title>This is a sample article</title>
<link>http://www.sample.com/sectin/hihskfhsdfhf</link>
<description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </description>
<pubDate>Sun, 14 Sep 2018 20:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

Php #1 code

```
<?php
$rss =simplexml_load_file("http://www.sample.com/outdoor/section/rss_xml");
$date_now = date("Y-m-d");
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) { 
$link = $item->link;
$title = $item->title;
$desc = $item->description;
$pubdate = $item->pubDate;
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pubdate));

if ($newDate == $date_now){
  echo "<h2>" . $title . "</h2>";
  echo "<p>" . $link . "</p>";
  echo "<p>" . $desc . "</p>";
  echo "<p>" . $pubdate . "</p>";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can look at the simple php xml parser. Then you can add some simple conditions to implement your task.

Comment: Thanks toor for some reason I was able to make my 2nd rule work but can not make rule 1 work. With code above if the item pubdate is equals to today's date then output the item but empty on my end do you know what might be causing the issue? thanks

Comment: You can try to make that using datetime function. Please review the manual with a comments below http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php